# Get Objects from Json

Tags: jquery, json

I have this Json

```
var data = "{"2144":{"quantity":"350"},"2095":{"quantity":"100"}}"
```

how can i get each value like this order using jquery?

2144 - quantity:350
2095 - quantity:100

Comment: You will want to start by converting the `data` string into a json object. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686237/3586783) to get you started. Then, you will basically be iterating through the json object keys and printing the key and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through each key/value pair in nested format like this:

```js
 var data = JSON.parse( '{"2144":{"quantity":"350"},"2095":    {"quantity":"100"}}');

    $.each(data , function(key , value){
     $.each(value , function(k , v ){
         console.log(key + '-' + k + ':' + v)
     });  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```